# Extract equivalent data from a raster brick into another raster brick with different crs, extent and resolution

Tags: r, raster, netcdf, coordinate-transformation

I have a nc file for daily precipitation data with 365 layers for a specific location. I have two raster bricks of this nc file with same data but with different extent, crs and resolution (but same ncell). One crs is 'longlat' and the other one is 'lcc'. How can I extract the same timeseries for the specific point from these two rasters?

Two bricks are as follow:

```
r_brick_1
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 584, 284, 165856, 365  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.01943937, 0.009507349  (x, y)
extent     : -160.2988, -154.7781, 17.96004, 23.51233  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : layer.1, layer.2, layer.3, layer.4,...
```

and

```
r_brick_2
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 584, 284, 165856, 365  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 1000, 1000  (x, y)
extent     : -5802750, -5518750, -622500, -38500  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=lcc +lat_0=42.5 +lon_0=-100 +lat_1=25 +lat_2=60 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : daymet_v4_daily_hi_prcp_1995.nc 
names      : X1995.01.01, X1995.01.02, X1995.01.03, X1995.01.04,...
```

Their plots for one day (1995.01.13) are as follow:

[image]

I used transformation of coordinates from 'longlat' into 'lcc' as follow:

```
library(sf)
st_point(c(-155.4906  , 19.1959)) |>
  st_sfc(crs = "WGS84") |>
  st_transform("+proj=lcc +lat_0=42.5 +lon_0=-100 +lat_1=25 +lat_2=60 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs") |>
  st_coordinates()
#>    X       Y
#> -5600839 -600886.7
```

the problem is that timeseries data of precipitation for point (-155.4906  , 19.1959) in 'longlat' raster is different from precipitation data for point (-5600839 -600886.7) in 'lcc' raster.

I have also tried flip function to check if X and Y has been swap between these coordinates but there was no match between two timeseries in anyway.

any help would be appreciated.